# Why can't I fully defragment my USB?

Tags: windows, usb, defragment

On my NTFS USB Drive, I need to have isos defragmented to be able to boot them. But neither Windows' native defragmentation nor UltraDefrag fully defragment my files, as verified by contig on Windows and filefrag on Linux.

Of course I can copy the files off and back on, but this really baffles me...

[image: screenshot]

There is plenty of free contiguous space on the drive, I checked that

Comment: Is this an SSD drive?  They should not be defragmented.

Comment: @John: It's probably a software requirement – sounds like the specific bootloader that implements "boot from ISO file" can't deal with multiple extents and mandates that the file be contiguous, either due to poor filesystem support or due to some technical need.

Comment: I am not asking for advice whether to defragment, I know I need it. I am asking whether there is some way to force it.
Easy2Boot creates a bootable partition from an ISO on the fly, that is why the file needs to be contiguous.

Comment: How much free space is available on that drive?

Answer (score -1):

[Easy2Boot](https://easy2boot.xyz/download/) includes a script at partition root that forces this. Which makes sense since this indeed an edge-case requirement.

I am still baffled no other tool was able to do it.

Comment: enforces what exactly?

Comment: What I asked for. It calls some windows commands that force defragment all files on the partition.

Answer (score -2):

Defragmentor programs work by making a copy of the file onto a block of contiguous free space on the same drive and then deleting the original file.
Some will try to first create a consolidated area of contiguous free space by moving the other files around (regardless of if the files were already non-fragmented or not) so that all the gaps in-between all the files are removed.

e.g. On an NTFS volume we might have a freshly formatted 8GB drive with 6GB of files:

FILE1_2GB FILE2_2GB FILE3_2GB (2GB FREE)

now we delete file2 and copy in a 1GB file4 and we get

FILE1_2GB (2GB FREE) FILE3_2GB **FILE4_1GB** (1GB FREE)

now we delete file3 and copy in a 1GB file5 and we get

FILE1_2GB (2GB FREE) **FILE5_1GB** (1GB FREE) FILE4_1GB (1GB FREE)

now we add a 3GB file6 which becomes fragmented...

FILE1_2GB **FILE6A_3GB** FILE5_1GB **FILE6B_3GB** FILE4_1GB (1GB FREE)

Now file6 is fragmented but there is only 1GB of free space, so we cannot defrag FILE6 or any file larger than 1GB.
If we delete FILE1 and we get

**(2GB FREE)** FILE6A_3GB FILE5_1GB FILE6B_3GB FILE4_1GB (1GB FREE)

but we still do not have enough *contiguous* free space to copy FILE6 into and make a new contiguous version.

So you see that a filesystem can contain fragmented files and fragmented areas of free space depending on its history. A defragmenter cannot make a new contiguous file if there is not enough free space on the volume.

One way around this would be to temporarily move the fragmented file to another drive, consolidate all the free spaces on the target drive and then copy back the file.

The Windows program WinContig requires a big-enough block of contiguous free space to already exist. The Windows GUI program Defraggler will try to consolidate free space first and then copy the file to the new free space area.
Defraggler also has an option to consolidate all free space blocks on a drive.

Another complication occurs when copying files to a drive - some programs open multiple streams when copying files (e.g. xcopy in default mode or direct download from the internet using a browser or when using multiple copy sessions to the same volume). This nearly always results in a fragmented file even if there was a single large block of contiguous free space on the target drive.

Defraggler is great for looking at the file map on a volume and examining how the files may be split over the drive.

Note that NTFS also normally places the MFT (master file table directory) at around the 3GB point on a Windows-formatted NTFS volume. So if you have an 8GB NTFS volume, you cannot place a contiguous 6GB file on it no matter what you try, because the MFT area is always in the middle of the drive!

Comment: I know how deframenting works, thank you, and I know there is enough continuous free space. But as you can see above, the defragmentation tools report a file as being non-fragmented which is clearly fragmented.

Comment: But you used the -a switch with contig64.exe - this only analyzed the file? What does E2B say about the file? Is your query that one utility incorrectly shows that a file is not fragmented or that one utility will not defrag a file?

Comment: This “answer” reads like it was generated by ChatGPT or taken from a click-bait blog post.